# Drupal 7. In 'node.tpl.php' how would I limit and offset the results?

Tags: php, drupal, limit, field

Apologies, novice Drupal question warning:

**Aim:** to split my outputted list of custom field images up so I can use them differently.

ie. In my node.tpl.php use the first 3 (most recent node) images in a slider. Then list the rest (offsetting the first three) just as plain images.

But I can't find how to limit my results. In my node template I can style all my images up using something like this:

```
<a href="<?php $nodeurl = url('node/'. $node->nid); echo $nodeurl; ?>"
 <img src="<?php print render (file_create_url($node->field_featured_image['und'][0]['uri'])); ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
</a>
```

But how do I limit the result? I guess this would work to ignore the first 3 results:

```
<?php foreach($node->field_featured_image as $k=>$v){
  if ($k < 3) continue;
  print render (file_create_url($node->field_featured_image['und'][0]['uri']));
 }
?>
```

But **not** in node.tpl as node.tpl appears to be a loop so the above code gets looped and the array key never gets past 0.

I think :/

Am I way off here with a basic misunderstanding of the templates?

Any pointers appreciated. Desperately trying to stick with drupal but finding it tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be mislead by what you're trying to accomplish, but you probably don't need to be hacking into node.tpl.php just yet.

If you aren't using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), start with that.
If you're trying to build a slider, use Views Rotator.
If you want something that's ready to be dropped in, use Enterprise Rotator. (basically Views Rotator and a Banner Slide content type built out already).

You can offset the images by using the pager options to either show a certain number, and offset the number of images queued up.

Or if you want to just use specific images, use [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue). Make a simple queue, add the nodes that contain the images you want, then in your View create a relationship (marked as required) to the nodequeue.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. That's really appreciated. I'll look into views again and maybe the pager options. I'm coming from wordpress so probably looking at things slightly wrong, I'm used to just querying the wp loop and in trying to find the drupal equivilent coming up blank. Thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: No problem. In Drupal, knowing site building will go a very long way to building an awesome site. Wordpress plugins are like fully cooked meals while Drupal modules are like ingredients you can throw together. Just check all the modules beforehand, because it's probably been done before. ;)

Happy site building.

Comment: No joke, that's the best explanation I've ever heard! I was trying to avoid modules like I would with wp (and hand code) - I see now I don't have to. Cheers Kyle! Awesome.